# Android Studio: Documentation not showing. No candidates found for method call `method`

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio, document

I have imported an Eclipse android project to Android Studio, using the steps given [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). When I click over a method or hover, its documentation displays empty.[image: like here]. Clicking in the Android Studio Manager, the documentation is installed. I have also changed the settings to display the documentation on mouse hover.

Comment: The screenshot is too small on my screen. Please copy and paste your code and the message here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I was hovering over the `toString()` method and it read `No candidates found for method ___.toString()`

Comment: Make sure if you have downloaded required SDK components like sources, documentation etc. Is your project compileable? I had the same problem. I installed SDK components via the manager and it works after reseting the AndroidStudio

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an issue with Android Studio.

I found a temporary solution for this

1. Tap on pin (Screenshot 1)
2. toggle the "auto-update from sources" button (Screenshot 2)
3. Now you can see the documentation in opened pin view
4. Now tap on Restore popup(Ctrl+Shift+Space) then you can see the documentation in pop up

[image: Screen shot 1]

[image: Screen shot 2]

[image: Screen shot 3]

**Note:** Once you close and reopen you will not find the documentation. You need to repeat above steps.

By hovering the class you will get the documentation and you can set this by checking the show quick doc option in settings(Screenshot 4)

[image: Screenshot 4]

Answer (score 0):

You could download the respective SDK platform source and it will load offline.

Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK
Select APi level
-Source for Api Level.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31995520)