# Is missing Documentation in class or field warning on Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

This morning the repo starts showing this warning on each class and field.

I've tried deleting cache, also look for some changes on the build gradle, look for some setting, but nothing works.

[missing documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNbs.png)

Comment: That's a class you wrote.  Did you write any documentation?  If not, then there's nothing to show.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601965/android-studio-documentation-not-showing-no-candidates-found-for-method-call) helps?

Comment: It happens on all project, i don't write any documentation, Gabe. No this didn't help Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

I resolved, going back into commits i found that someone made a modification on a file located on

.idea-> inspectionProfiles-> Project_Default.xml

and then i found (among others) this one inspection_tool Tag on true.

I omit changes and will put it on ignore, but it get solved put it on false.

<inspection_tool class="KDocMissingDocumentation" enabled="true" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="true" />

Happy coding Folks!

Answer (score 0):

Same can be achieved in Studio interface by opening `Android Studio -> Settings -> Inspections -> Kotlin -> Other Problems` and unticking `Missing KDoc comments`. If you have the same issue with Javadoc, it is found in the `Java -> Javadoc` section.

These boxes control what is being checked by Studio's Lint. The warning you are seeing is telling you you haven't written javadoc/kdoc for those classes/methods, and by default lint checks for those. By unchecking them you tell lint not to bother.